# .Net Core, accessing settings without creating additional class

Tags: .net-core

In .Net Core, 
why do we have to use a class to map appsettigns.json ?
isn't it an extra code when i have to add a property inside the settings class each time i add a config key ?
is there another way like standard .Net ?

Comment: If setting key used only once in the application and key itself never changes, then having a class probably doesn't make much sense, but having a class will provide better maintainability and readability. With class will be much easier to configure it for testing purposes, then having dependency on `IConfiguration` everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You always can use IConfiguration interface to read you config like this

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        var x = configuration["setting1"];
        var y = configuration["block1:setting1"];
        var z = configuration["block1__setting1"];
        var w = configuration.GetSection("block1")["setting1"];
    }
}
```

But it means you will inject your IConfiguration in all types that depend on it and all that types will be familiar with configuration names and structure. If you will refactor your appsetting.json you will have to find and fix all that places.